# If I know that my variables are all empirically true predictors, then what analysis can be left out?

Tags: model

If I know that my variables are all empirically true predictors, then what analysis can be left out? I.e. what kind of statistical measures of goodness are not imporant.

That's, my model contains only components that all certainly do predict the outcome variable and I also know the ranges where the observations truly predict something. Thus I can essentially produce a true prediction already by just measuring the variables. But I've been led to study models still in order to perhaps "round" possible outlier situations in the observations, since some variables may have cross-effects.

Thus I'm finding that I would not need to study "statistical significance", since I already know that the model is empirically sound.

But is there a more formal explanation as to what can be left out in this kind of situation?

Comment: The statistical analysis you need depends on your objectives.  Which ones do you have in mind?

Comment: @whuber Maybe I could ask rather, what analysis can I leave out. I.e. what are not significant statistics. Such as p-values. Since I know the predictions are true, then I would not need a p-value to tell me, whether they're significant.

Comment: That is true.  But since you wouldn't be investigating whether variables are significant, why would you even apply such a statistical test?  You apply statistical procedures that are relevant to your objectives.

Comment: @whuber Well it could be useful to e.g. keep track of means etc. in case the training set becomes very large. Since if the initial assumptions are tested on a smaller sample, then it's possible that when the sample grows, new, previously unknown information could become available, but then it would be difficult to discover it manually from e.g. 100000 samples. Or know, where new information occurs, w/o studying each new sample manually. Essentially, I have strong trust in initial assumptions, but it's possible that when sample grows very large, they will require some adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

If you mainly care about prediction, you need to determine the model's functional form (e.g. consider a linear vs. a more flexible model) and estimate the model's parameters (start with point estimates but also consider interval estimates and perhaps densities (Bayesian) or confidence distributions (fiducial)). You may also want to estimate the model's expected predictive performance on new data.

If you care about causal effects, in addition to the above, you need to find an estimator that yields causal effects as contrasted to merely parameters of the conditional distribution of the dependent variable given the regressors.